# I pass a string as function argument, can I ever access that string in that function

Tags: c

In C, if I pass a string as function argument, I will have the pointer variable that points to the base address of that string. But we can still print the entire string that has been passed as argument. So  I was wondering if I can ever access the whole string in that function and not just limited to printing it?

```
void PrintHelloWorld(char *name){
    printf("Hello World %s \n",name);
}


int main(){
    char x[] = "John";
    PrintHelloWorld(x);

}
```

Comment: yes, you access it, i.e. read it like printf did, and also change it if you want. When you pass a pointer to a function, the function can change the "pointed-to-data"

Comment: What do you mean? You can access the whole string as a pinter to the beginning of the string is passed. Unless you meant something else?

Comment: See simple example here: https://ideone.com/sKkEVN

Comment: If the string will NOT be modified in the function, better to pass as `const char *` so the compiler can further optimize the function.

Answer (score 1):

*String* is not precise enough in C when it comes to details of memory allocation for the characters. String literals can be assigned in two ways:

```
char a[] = "ABCDE";
char *p = "ZYXWV";
```

`a` is a "plain" array of chars. As if created by first declaring `char a[6];` The terminating 0 is added by the compiler.

`p` is a special case because the array of 5 chars plus the 0 has to be stored somewhere, but there is no array variable.

The difference would not really matter, but e.g. gcc decides to put these non-object arrays into `.rodata` section:

```
String dump of section '.rodata':
  [     4]  ZYXWV


String dump of section '.data':
  [     8]   @
  [    10]  ABCDE
  [    19]
```

So

```
const char *p = "ZYXWV";
```

is the safer and clearer way to define a read-only string.

The function declaration `(char *name)` can reflect that:

`(const char *name)` to declare no modification will happen.

`(char name[12])` to *show* that one expects `name` to be allocated. (the compiler needs `[static 12]` to make a difference)